# Magento 1.9.3 - Mailing Solution for Magento Multistore

Tags: magento-1.9, email, multistore

We are using a Magento 1.9.3 instance with multiple websites set up.
Every website has it's own Mailbox and Mail-Address. And their own Domains.

These are either hosted at **all-inkl.com** or **gmail**.

```
Website A -> Domain A -> info@domain-a.com -> Mailbox hosted at all-inkl.com 
Website B -> Domain B -> info@domain-b.com -> Mailbox hosted at all-inkl.com
Website C -> Domain C -> info@domain-c.com -> Mailbox hosted at gmail
Website D -> Domain D -> info@domain-d.com -> Mailbox hosted at gmail
```

The MX records are obviously showing to the Mailservers according to the mailboxes.

The Extension we are using for Mail is **SMTPPro**

SMTPPro doesn't support Multistore or at least doesn't support setting up multiple mail servers. I managed to change some code to allow me to configure different mail servers and login credentials depending on the website scope level.

**Problem:**, In general, these settings work but they don't seem to be used in every situation. This is not a surprise because the extension isn't meant to work with different scope level so it might not take these into account in every situation.

**Result:** Not all the emails are being sent.

**Example:** A mail from Website C should be sent. 
The mailbox for Website C is hosted on Gmail
Now the system doesn't seem to check the server configuration on scope level but instead goes with the default one which is the one for Website A.
The e-mail address is taken from the store configuration.
I assume this is what happens: SMTPPro trying to send a mail from info@domain-c.com via the Default server which is the all-inkl.com one.

Result: *Sender address rejected: not owned by user*

**What we want to achieve:** That all emails from all the websites are going out to the customers.
Since I think this is not a very uncommon task: are there any good concepts on how to solve this?

Here's what we already tried:

**Solution 1:**
Modify the Extension's code in a way that it will always take the correct server configuration.
**Problem:** I am not able to do this myself.

**Solution2:**
Using a service like SendGrid, which can be used as default SMTP server, while all the mailboxes stay the same.
**Problem:** I tried this but with the shared IP in the Essentials Plan we had a failure rate of about 30% emails not being delivered.
This is because of the IP being blacklisted on several blacklists.
So the other 70% that are not being blocked is probably directly going into the spam filter of the inbox, at least that's what happened with the test emails I sent to my own mail addresses.
I set some DNS (CNAME) entries according to the SendGrid Guides along with implementing SPF and DKIM but that didn't change too much.
For my understanding, once the IP is blocked it's blocked.
I wrote to the support but basically got told to upgrade to Pro, which is not an option because it's too expensive.